# gedit in LXDE: black bar

Tags: gedit

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with LXDE desktop environment.

When I use the normal Ubuntu desktop, everything is normal. When I'm using LXDE however, the bar with all opened files is black. You can see what I mean here:

[image]

Comment: This should go to AskUbuntu isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

I think I have found a solution that works. I changed the LXDE theme to Radiance using lxappearance. Gedit has no black bars now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be related to the LXDE themes not being GTK 3 compatible. There is some advice which will work around the problem and relevant links to more details here:

http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7127

Answer (score 2):

Since this didn't have good answers here and I was having the same problem in XFCE. [I asked a very similar question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476249/in-xubuntu-there-are-black-unreadable-tabs-in-gtk-applications-such-as-gedit)

The fix is as simple as choosing a different theme from the `xfce4-appearance-settings` dialog available from the main menu under "Settings" -> "Appearance".  In LXDE the way to change themes is with the `lxappearance` command as codefx states in his answer.

[image: xfce appearance dialog]

The "Raleigh" and "Industrial" themes have this problem. Many others such as "Greybird", "Orion", and "Radiance" do not.

Here is the problem fixed running with the "Orion" theme:

[image]

Comment: This method works, however the gui might be different (at least on my version). In the main menu: select preferences/customize look and feel. The tab is called widget instead of style.